How to change the space between item and subitem in Beamer?
It is possible to increase the vertical space between items in an itemize list. But it does not work for the separation between items and the following subitem.
How can I increase the vertical separation between an item and the next subitem?
MWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}

% Space between items, step 1: define new item
\newlength{\wideitemsep}
\setlength{\wideitemsep}{\itemsep}
\addtolength{\wideitemsep}{6pt}
% Space between items, step 2: reconfigure itemize
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\wideitemsep}\olditem%
}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Item separation - Added space; default item/subitem space}

\begin{itemize}
\item Current value of \texttt{$\backslash$itemsep}: \the\itemsep
\item This is the text of an item
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the text of the first subitem. It is too close to the parent item
\item This is the text of a subitem
\end{itemize}
\item This is the text of an item
\end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}



If the answer meets your request please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer. Thank you!

Hi Simon, thank you for your answer! Great suggestion. I could not return to it, but I will. I am looking for a solution that focuses on the space between items, as it will be more natural. But I will return to it soon. Best

You can use the \addtobeamertemplate{⟨element name⟩}{⟨pre-text⟩}{⟨post-text⟩} command to add (to the pre-text) a zero-width rule to change the space before and after an item or sub-item.

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}

\setlength{\partopsep}{1ex} % Additional space between first item and the top (only this works)

%% \addtobeamertemplate{⟨element name⟩}{⟨pre-text⟩}{⟨post-text⟩}
%% \rule[raise the box above the baseline]{<width>}{<height>} <<<<<<<<<<
\addtobeamertemplate{itemize item}{\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}}{} % <<<<<<<<<<<<  added
\addtobeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}}{} % <<<<<<<<<<< added

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \frametitle{Item separation - Added space; default item/subitem space}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This is the text of the first item
            \item This is the text of an item
            \begin{itemize}
                \item This is the text of the first subitem. It is too close to the parent item.
                \item This is the text of a subitem
            \end{itemize}
            \item This is the text of an item
            \item This is the text of an item
            
        \end{itemize}
        
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}

To visualize how the rule works, temporarily use a non-zero width rule like
\rule[-0.5ex]{1pt}{4ex}.
This is how it looks like with the rules:

With a 2pt-width rule for the subitem to differentiate it. The commands are:
\addtobeamertemplate{itemize item}{\rule[-0.5ex]{1pt}{4ex}}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{4ex}}{}


Thank you for your answer! It is an interesting solution. Changing the icons might interfere with the beamer themes, though. Let us see if a solution that could only change the vertical separation appears

@Andre This solution does not change the icons

Being more precise, following the comment of samcarter, this solution does not change the icon, but adds a new element to the item

@Andre ... and why would a new element interfere with beamer themes?

A change in the theme might show previously invisible elements when, for example, the background color changes. It might not be the case for this solution. It is just a preference for a solution that involves changes in spaces
